Spring Boot Header Not Found
I’m having trouble adding a header to my HTML pages in my Spring Boot application using Thymeleaf. My header.html file is located in src/main/resources/templates/fragments/header.html. When I include it using the following line:
<div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: common-header}"></div>
it works fine when I run the application in VS Code. However, it doesn’t work when I package the application into a .jar file and deploy it. Could someone help me fix this issue?
Some research doesnt helped me

Add your pom.xml and what is the error you get?

Did you try - spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/

That is already the default so respecifying it won't change a bit.
